# combine and write out a combination in VBA

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, combinations

I have written some code to read into an Array or Combination a list on non consecutive values. The Array writes out by writing the values of the array into a string variable separated by coma's i.e. (mystring = Join(Pie, ","). This works okay except when the array has a blank or a duplicate, it ends up with coma's with nothing in between them. The Combination works better because but I don't know how to write out the contents of a Combination to a single cell. i.e. The Combination is a list of fruit. If their is a duplicate then I don't want to include it in the output. I have the unique value code working but I may end up with an output such as Apple, , Orange, Grape, , , Peach. When I use Combination, the values are read into correctly but I'd like to write it out as only unique values separated by coma's i.e. (Apple, Orange, Grape, Peach) Any help would be great. I can provide some sample code if necessary.  I just need some help on how to use and manipulate Combinations in Excel VBA.  (I would even like to sort the items within the combination alphabetically if possible) Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could include your code and give specific examples of where the current code doesn't give what you want it to give.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7198154/combination-algorithm-in-excel-vba

Comment: I'd split the array into a range and then rejoin the array if cell <> "". http://www.globaliconnect.com/excel/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=270:excel-vba-string-functions-split-join-concatenate&catid=79&Itemid=475

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
Dim result As String
Dim fruit As Variant

fruit = Array("Banana", "Apple", "Banana", "Orange", "", "Apple")

For i = 0 To UBound(fruit)

    If fruit(i) <> "" And InStr(result, fruit(i)) = 0 Then
        If result <> "" Then
            result = result + ", " + fruit(i)
        Else
            result = fruit(i)
        End If
    End If
Next i

MsgBox result 'returns: "Banana, Apple, Orange"
```

**Edit:** If the fruits are stored on the Sheet, just loop trough the cells and add them to the array.

**Edit 2.0:**

```
Dim result As String
Dim fruit As Variant, allfruits As Variant
Dim i As Integer
Dim success As Boolean

allfruits = Array("Apple", "Orange", "Mango", "Banana")   'Fruits sorted by Importance
fruit = Array("Banana", "Apple", "Banana", "Orange", "", "Apple")

For i = 0 To UBound(allfruits)
    success = False
    For Each element In fruit
        If element = allfruits(i) And success = False Then
            success = True
        End If
    Next element
    If success = True Then
        If result = "" Then
            result = allfruits(i)
        Else
            result = result + ", " + allfruits(i)
        End If
    End If
Next i

MsgBox result 'returns: "Apple, Orange, Banana"
```

Comment: that worked great. Lastly, I'd like to refer to a look up table of values say 1-10 and order the items of the array from 1-10. I.e. If Apple = 5 and Banana = 2 and grapes = 9 then the array would be reordered "Banana, Apple, Grape". This look up table is on another sheet but if need to hard code it with static values in VBA I can. Thanks.

Comment: 1. Can you post a picture of how the look up tables you mean look like and Secondly, do you mean that the Fruits should be sorted by value (smallest first, ..., biggest Value last)?

Comment: No access. On a separate sheet I have a list of 10 fruits in a particular order that I want to be listed in the array in a particular order based on the table from that separate sheet. i.e. Row 1 Column B = 1 and Row 1 Column C = Apple, Then 1 row below that I have 2 and Pear and then 3 and Orange and so on... This table dictates the order the fruit is listed in the array. In other words if Pear comes up first as the array is being built, it is added to the array, then if Apple comes up after the pear, I want it to be before Pear in the array. Hope this helps explain it. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Are the ten fruits all of the fruits that are 'possible'?

Comment: Yes, the list is static and they are all possible. I loop through a 'bag of goodies' and if the bag has 4 fruits then I want them to display in a particular order regardless of the order they are taken out of the bag. Thx in advance.