# Get all combinations where first item's order matters, but the order of the rest doesn't

Tags: excel, vba, combinations

So I have been trying to solve this for last 2 days. Suppose in column A, I have

```
A
B
C
D
```

Now I want ALL combinations of 3 letters out of these 4 where each letter will have to come to the 1st position. For example,

```
ABC
ACD
ABD
BAC
BDA
BCA
CAB
CBD
CAD
...
etc
```

Note: `ACB` and `ABC` are same because 2nd, and 3rd letter order does not matter but every letter will have to show up in the first position.So I want only one from 'ACB' and 'ABC'

This example is for 3 out of 4, but I want something for 5 out of 10. 
Can anyone help me out with this? I can't find any formula and tried writing macro/VBA but didn't work. I would greatly appreciate your help.

Comment: [edit] your question to include 'macro/VBA but didnt work' and ask a specific question. [ask]

Comment: And also... provide the way of how you would do it manually as this is part of the solution, it is not clear in your explanation the combinations that you are searching for.

Answer (score 0):

I consider this as 2 step:
1. pick up 3 letters from 4
2. make combination of this 3 letters.
My result as below:
ABC
ACB
BAC
BCA
CBA
CAB
ABD
ADB
BAD
BDA
DBA
DAB
ACD
ADC
CAD
CDA
DCA
DAC
BCD
BDC
CBD
CDB
DCB
DBC

Answer (score 0):

- This problem was really fun working out, I had found some algorithms [Here](https://web.archive.org/web/20110714075112/http://www.merriampark.com/comb.htm) and [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7202691/9565106) that can get the combinations of n elements, but the twist of your question making all elements be at position 1 was really exciting.
- This sub will do what you asked for no matter how many n-elements(characters) you have and for any r-place you want, as long as `r <= n`.
- I tried commenting what I'm able to explain, (although I left some quite hard to get lines that I will get back to later).

**[EDIT]:**

I Finished commenting the possible tricky parts, and the final product looks mouthful and quite messy, but it might help someone out there in the future, so I'm going to leave it as is.

```
Option Base 1

Sub getCombinations()

    Dim ws As Worksheet, srcCol As String, desCol As String, places As Integer
    Dim lastRow As Integer, elements() As String, elmntsCount As Integer, nCr As Long, cmbnationCount As Long

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet 'Pick the sheet you're working on
    srcCol = "A" 'The column that has all the characters in singles
    desCol = "B" 'The column you wish to put the resulted combinations into

    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.count, srcCol).End(xlUp).Row
    ReDim elements(1 To lastRow)
    For i = 1 To lastRow
        elements(i) = ws.Range(srcCol & i).Value2
    Next i

    elmntsCount = UBound(elements) - LBound(elements) + 1 'The total number of single elements (characters)

    Do
        places = InputBox("Enter the number of places (r):" & vbNewLine & "I.E, How many characters you want in each combination?" & vbNewLine & "(Places) must be <= " & elmntsCount, "Define the places", 3)
        If (places <= elmntsCount) Then Exit Do
        MsgBox "Places (r) must be less than or equal to the total count of characters (n) that are in column (" & srcCol & ")." & vbNewLine & "Please, choose a smaller integer for the (places)."
    Loop

    'To Calculate the number of combinations: first place takes all the possible elements and the rest of the places can be calculated using nCr
    'Where n is (total elements -1) and r is (total places -1).
    'So the total number of combinations will be: elmntsCount * nCr. And Excel has a built in function for nCr (COMBIN)
    nCr = Application.WorksheetFunction.Combin(elmntsCount - 1, places - 1) 'represents how many combinations are there disregarding the character in the first place
    cmbnationCount = elmntsCount * nCr

    MsgBox "There are " & cmbnationCount & " combinations." & vbNewLine & "I've put them in column (" & desCol & ")."

    ws.Range(desCol & 1 & ":" & desCol & cmbnationCount).ClearContents

    Dim comb As String, combCount As Long: combCount = 0
    Dim indices() As Integer, add As Integer: add = 0

    ReDim indices(1 To places)
    For i = 1 To places
        indices(i) = i
    Next i

    Do While (True)

        comb = ""
        'Write current combination
        For j = 1 To places
            comb = comb & elements(indices(j))
        Next j
        combCount = combCount + 1
        ws.Range(desCol & combCount).Value2 = comb

        'Locate last non-max index

        'For different combinations where order doesn't matter, The maximum index each place can have is (elmntsCount - places + i) where i is the index's nth place
        'So for 7 characters 4 places, the max index for the last place is 7-4+4 = 7. The one before it has a max of 7-4+3 = 6. So all the max indices are 4,5,6,7 in that order
        'But since we want to account for the possibility of some place having an index the same as the 1st place's index -given our special twist of the first place-,
        'then the max of each place's index become one less than the original max when the first place's index is greater than or equal to that place's index
        'And that's what the abs() part in the condition of the while loop is about:
        'When (first place's index) is greater than or equal to (the max index of the tested place) make that place's max index 1 less. Otherwise keep it as the original max
        i = places
        Do While (indices(i) = elmntsCount - places + i - Abs(indices(1) >= elmntsCount - places + i))
            i = i - 1
            If i = 1 Then
                'All indices after 1st index have maxed out
                indices(1) = indices(1) + 1
                If indices(1) > elmntsCount Then Exit Sub 'We've reached the end.
                indices(2) = 0
                i = 2
                'We've reached the first index, so increment it and start all over with the second one
                Exit Do
            End If
        Loop

        'Increment the current index, and if after the incremention it equals the first index, then add 1 more
        indices(i) = indices(i) + 1 + Abs((indices(i) + 1) = indices(1)) 'The absolute value part adds 1 if the index after incremention equals the first index, and adds 0 otherwise

        'Increment the following indices
        For j = i + 1 To places
            If (indices(j - 1) + 1) = indices(1) Then add = 1 'Check if an index after incrementing would equal the first index, and add 1 if so
            indices(j) = indices(j - 1) + 1 + add 'Each index is (1+add) more than the index before it
            add = 0
        Next j
    Loop
End Sub
```