# How to convert 123 TO 12, 13, 21, 23, 31, 32

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am just learning vba.  I want to change the number 123 to 12 13 21 23 31 32.  But please help me because I don't know how to do it.  I am sorry if I am writing wrongly.  I'm not very familiar with English

I still don't know where to start.

Answer (score 0):

You can find several answers in another question here:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7198154/combination-algorithm-in-excel-vba
```

[Combination Algorithm in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7198154/combination-algorithm-in-excel-vba)